# How do I convert List of Macros in to String in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have a list of macros in Elixir and trying to put quotes around it, please help me.

I want to convert `[Id, Node, Timestamp]` into `"[Id, Node, Timestamp]"`.

How would I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

`[Id, Node, Timestamp]` is a list of **atoms** not a list of **macros**.

Atoms are plain terms and hence plain old good [`Kernel.inspect/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#inspect/2) would perfectly do.

```
inspect [Id, Node, Timestamp]
#⇒ "[Id, Node, Timestamp]"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a quoted expression, I believe [Macro.to_string/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Macro.html#to_string/2) is what you're looking for.

```
iex> ast = quote do: [Id, Node, Timestamp]
[Id, Node, Timestamp]
iex> Macro.to_string(ast)
"[Id, Node, Timestamp]"
```

Like Aleksei pointed out, however, the AST for a list of atoms is itself, so if that's all you're trying to convert to a string, [Kernel.inspect/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#inspect/2) accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Quoting a list of atoms makes zero sense since both lists and atoms are already quoted expressions, equal to their AST. `Macro.to_string([Id, Node, Timestamp])` has the same effect.

Comment: Macro.to_string(ast) helped. Thanks!